# PHP: How to store cart data (foreach loop) into different variables to store in MySQL

Tags: php, html

Good afternoon,

I have searched for an answer to this query and the closest I could find was this:  [Storing elements in an array at each iteration of a foreach on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911382/storing-elements-in-an-array-at-each-iteration-of-a-foreach-on-php)

I am building my own eCommerce platform using PHP and I have gotten to the point now where I can add items to my cart.

I am currently building the checkout page but I dont know how to store each product ordered into different variables so that I can store them into MySQL.

The following code allows me to populate the relevant data I just dont know how to store this data into the variables:

```html
<?php 
session_start();

include '../connection.php';

 $cartProducts = array();
 
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
 
  
    
  echo "Product Details Acquired:" . "<br>";       
  echo $item["product_name"] . "<br>"; 
  echo $item["quantity"] . "<br>";
  echo "£".$item["product_price"] . "<br> <br>";
    
  } 


 //setting username variable
 $myusername = $_SESSION['login_user'];

 // getting client info
 include '../connection.php';
  $sql="SELECT id, username, phone, email from clients WHERE username='$myusername'";
   if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
    //Presenting data from array  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
      $client_id= $row['id'];
      $client_phone= $row['phone'];
      $client_user= $row['username'];
      $client_email= $row['email'];
      
      echo "User details acquired" ."<br>";
      echo $client_id ."<br>";
      echo $client_phone ."<br>";
      echo $client_user ."<br>";
      echo $client_email ."<br>";
     }
    }
    else {
      echo "No client data found...";
     }
  
 
?>
```

This produces all of the data i need:

Product Details Acquired:
Chair
1
£129.89

Product Details Acquired:
Double Bed
1
£1999

User details acquired
4
2147483647
coreyhowe12
corey@test.com

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: you can store the products in an `array`

Comment: I guess instead of echo-ing the product informations you want to store the values in variables to use later on. In that case you could store the values in an array.

Comment: Thanks guys, i guessed that this would be the case, how do i do this? Ive tried various code but had no luck... (code from the example question)

Comment: So you are basically asking how to write `$product_name = $item["product_name"];`?

Comment: Ok so what I want to do is:   Foreach loop gets all products. Stores product 1 data into variables, then stores product 2 into variables (product id, name, price quantity). Then I want to store into MySQL (I know how to do this) I just need a hand populating the variables.

Comment: Why don't you use an insert statement there in foreach loop?

Comment: Ive tried this after each loop:   
$sql_statement="INSERT INTO orders (product_id, product_name, quantity, total_price) VALUES ("$item['product_id']", "$item['product_name']", "$item['quantity']", "$item['product_price']")";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `INSERT` query in your `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){

   // use your product attributes like this.
   $product_name = $item["product_name"];
   $quantity = $item["quantity"];

   // then use insert query like this
   $insert = "INSERT INTO products (`product_name`, .. other columns ..) VALUES ('$product_name', .. other column values ..)";
   mysqli_query($connection, $insert);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not store it in an array and then loop through the array for your insert query?